# How to upload the image using LinkedIn API without using curl request?

Tags: linkedin-api

I've used the **curl** request to upload an image which successfully worked for me.

```
curl -i --upload-file ~/Desktop/Myimage.jpg -H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' "https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQLKRJOn_yNw6wAAAW2T0DWnRStny4dzsNVJjlF3aN4-H3ZR9Div77kKoQ&app=1983914&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1Dnjy796bpjEY1"
```

I've tried using the same request with "**request**" package which got failed and redirected me to the "*404 page not found*" LinkedIn page.

Here is the code:

```
const options = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            method: 'put',
            url: mediaUploadUrl
        }

fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(request(options, function(err, httpsResponse, body){
            if ( err ) {
                console.log('err', err);
                response(callback, 400, err);
            } else {
                console.log(body);
                response(callback, 200, { mediaUrn });
            }
        }));
```

Documentation page that I've followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares

#linkedin

Comment: here is the sample java code https://stackoverflow.com/a/74143725/1132056

Answer (score 0):

The request method is supposed to be POST but you are sending PUT instead, below code should work.

```
const options = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        method: 'post',
        url: mediaUploadUrl
    }

fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(request(options, function(err, httpsResponse, body) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.log('err', err);
            response(callback, 400, err);
        } else {
            console.log(body);
            response(callback, 200, { mediaUrn });
        } 
 }));
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've already tried both the method (POST, PUT) and none of them worked for me. 
Strange thing is that it was working fine before using PUT request.